# EF6 forcing the use of my integrated account

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to use "Update-database" from package Manager console, i always get the error Login Failed for user 'TEMP\IGIT02T. although this use is defined as SA and DB owner

I found many articles and similar questions but didn't solve my issue.
What i did, i created an account in sql server "userID:testUser password:Test#2016" changed my connection string and set Integrated Security= false.

Now if i run `PM> Update-Database` i still get error

```
Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14 Login failed for user 'TEMP\IGIT02T'
```

I tested the following connection strings:

```
<add name="TestDB" connectionString="Data Source=XXT0006\MSSQLServerDv;User Id=testUser;Password=Test#2016; Initial Catalog=TestDbEf"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

add name="TestDB" connectionString="Data Source=XXT0006\MSSQLServerDv;User Id=testUser;Password=Test#2016; Initial Catalog=TestDbEf;Integrated Security=false" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

In my DbContext class

```
public TestEFDBContext()
        : base("TestDB")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TestEFDBContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TestEFDBContext>());

    }
```

why it doesn't pick the local sql login, also if i try to login directly to SQL server using testUser or TEMP\IGIT02T I have no issue and i can CRUD create and delete databases.

Thank you

Comment: you are missing a semicolon after your username: "User Id=testUser;Password=Test#2016;"

Comment: Thx @Jay, i did but i still get the same issue

Comment: Update-Database uses the Startup Project to determine the connection string to use, could this be the issue? You would get that error if you are connecting to the wrong server.

Comment: @samjudson Yes i'm connecting to the correct project